# Obtain Kerberos ticket in C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c, kerberos, mit-kerberos

**Does anyone know how to get a ticket from the Key Distribution Center (KDC) using the MIT krb5 API in C/C++?**

I already have a working Java Client which uses GSS-API to obtain a ticket from the KDC (using a local TGT) and forwards it to a Java Server.

The server accepts the security context using the following logic:

```
private GSSContext acceptSecurityContext(Subject serverSubject, final byte[] kerberosServiceTicket) {
 return Subject.doAs(serverSubject, (PrivilegedAction<GSSContext>) () -> {
            GSSContext gssContext;
            try {
                gssContext = manager.createContext((GSSCredential) null);
            } catch (GSSException ex) {
                LOGGER.warn("Could not create Kerberos gssContext: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                return null;
            }
            try {
                gssContext.acceptSecContext(kerberosServiceTicket, 0, kerberosServiceTicket.length);
            } catch (GSSException ex) {
                LOGGER.warn("Could not accept security context: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                return null;
            }
            return gssContext;
        });
}
```

I am trying to implement a C client - similar to the Java one - using  MIT krb5 API and I can't seem to make it work. So far this is my C client code:

```
    krb5_context context;
    krb5_ccache ccache;
    krb5_creds *outCreds = NULL;
    krb5_creds inCreds;
    int retval;
    char *principal = "...";

    retval = krb5_init_secure_context(&context);
    ...

    retval = krb5_cc_default(context, &ccache);
    ...

    memset(&inCreds, 0, sizeof(inCreds));
    retval = krb5_parse_name(context, principal, &inCreds.server);
    ...

    retval = krb5_cc_get_principal(context, ccache, &inCreds.client);
    ...

    retval = krb5_get_credentials(context, 0, ccache, &inCreds, &outCreds);
    ...

    // also tried using the following: krb5Ticket->enc_part.ciphertext.data
    // (maybe this is the correct way, but I should somehow decrypt it and use krb5Ticket->enc_part2 ?)
    // retval = krb5_decode_ticket(&outCreds->ticket, &krb5Ticket);
    // ...

    char *base64KerberosTicket = base64_encode(outCreds->ticket.data, strlen(outCreds->ticket.data));

    char *response = loginKerberos(base64KerberosTicket);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further reading it appears that my approach was not correct for my use case. I should have used GSS-API directly.

The following snippet works:

```
gss_name_t get_spn(char *spn)
{
    OM_uint32 maj_stat;
    OM_uint32 min_stat;
    gss_buffer_desc name_buf = GSS_C_EMPTY_BUFFER;
    gss_name_t spn_gss_name = GSS_C_NO_NAME;

    name_buf.value = spn;
    name_buf.length = strlen(name_buf.value);

    maj_stat = gss_import_name(&min_stat, &name_buf, GSS_KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL_NAME, &spn_gss_name);

    if (GSS_ERROR(maj_stat))
    {
        display_status("Major status", maj_stat, GSS_C_GSS_CODE);
        display_status("Minor status", min_stat, GSS_C_MECH_CODE);
    }

    return spn_gss_name;
}

char* init_sec_context(char *spn)
{
    OM_uint32 maj_stat;
    OM_uint32 min_stat;
    OM_uint32 flags = GSS_C_REPLAY_FLAG | GSS_C_SEQUENCE_FLAG | GSS_C_MUTUAL_FLAG;
    gss_ctx_id_t gss_context = GSS_C_NO_CONTEXT;
    gss_name_t spn_gss_name = get_spn(spn);
    gss_buffer_desc output_token;
    char *base64_encoded_kerberos_token = NULL;
    maj_stat = gss_init_sec_context( //
            &min_stat, // minor_status
            GSS_C_NO_CREDENTIAL, // claimant_cred_handle
            &gss_context, // context_handle
            spn_gss_name, // target_name
            GSS_C_NO_OID, // mech_type of the desired mechanism
            flags, // req_flags
            0, // time_req for the context to remain valid. 0 for default lifetime.
            GSS_C_NO_CHANNEL_BINDINGS, // channel bindings
            GSS_C_NO_BUFFER, // input token 
            NULL, // actual_mech_type
            &output_token, // output token 
            NULL, // ret_flags
            NULL // time_req
            );
    if (GSS_ERROR(maj_stat))
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (output_token.length != 0)
    {
        base64_encoded_kerberos_token = base64_encode(output_token.value, output_token.length, &(output_token.length));
    }

    if (gss_context != GSS_C_NO_CONTEXT)
    {
        gss_delete_sec_context(&min_stat, &gss_context, GSS_C_NO_BUFFER);
    }
    if (spn_gss_name != GSS_C_NO_NAME)
    {
        gss_release_name(&min_stat, &spn_gss_name);
    }
    gss_release_buffer(&min_stat, &output_token);

    return base64_encoded_kerberos_token;
}
```